Interactive proportional value of a pandas column displayed using altair pie chart in python?
I have a sample dataframe created using the snippet below
categories = [
    "Network Issue",
    "Hardware Failure",
    "Software Bug",
    "User Error",
    "Other",
]
locations = ["Location A", "Location B", "Location C", "Location D", "Location E"]
data = {
    "Root Cause": [random.choice(categories) for _ in range(20)],
    "LocationName": [random.choice(locations) for _ in range(20)],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

I wanted to get the following -

A pie (or donut) chart using Altair's alt.Chart(source).mak_arc() method whereby the theta is based on the proportional value of the Root Cause column i.e. - (sum('Root Cause') / count('Root Cause'))
Allow users to select an arc of the pie (or donut) chart and have a table display those rows based on selection.

I have tried creating the pie chart using the following
import altair as alt
# Create the pie chart
pie_chart = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_arc()
    .encode(
        theta=alt.Theta(field="Root Cause", type="nominal", aggregate="count"),
        color=alt.Color(field="Root Cause", type="nominal"),
        tooltip=[
            "Root Cause",
            alt.Tooltip(field="Root Cause", type="nominal"),
            alt.Tooltip(field="count()", title="Percentage"),
        ],
    )
)

pie_chart

This gives me a pie chart but doesnt display the percentage value upon hovering or displayed as text.
Also what would be a way to link the selection to a table adjacent to the pie chart?
I have tried looking at the docs here and here but havent got much luck, please advice.

(1) See this gallery example for how to compute the percentage/proportion out of a total using transforms. (2) The table would be constructed according to the example you linked (also here in the docs). Then you set up a selection that filters the table based on the selected  Root Cause  in the chart as described in the Selection Targets section of the docs.

Do we have to use the same data source for the donut chart and the table? I have create the grouped dataframe consisting of 3 columns = Root Cause | Proportion | NumberOfSeconds (using a timestamp column). The original dataframe contains the 'longer' version of the data. I am trying to use your suggestions to create a donut chart using the grouped dataframe and a table using the longer dataframe. The selection_point using the Root Cause field from the donut chart doesnt filter the table. Can you advice how this can be achieved?

I managed to get my question answered however I havent figured out the way to remove the border in the mark_text() 'table' . I tried adding mark_text(strokwidth=0, stroke=None) but still see a border per column. Can this be removed?

Would setting stroke=None in the view configuration help? As in this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/violin_plot.html

Thanks for the recommendations @joelostblom. I did the following to achieve what I needed -

Aggregate the original dataframe to reduce it to a smaller number of rows and then draw the pie chart based on this aggregated dataframe

Pie chart using reduced/ aggregated dataframe
selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['Root Cause'])
pieChart = (
    alt.Chart(forPieChart)
    .mark_arc(innerRadius=80)
    .encode(
        theta=alt.Theta(field="Percentage", type="quantitative"),
        color=alt.Color(field="Root Cause", type="nominal", legend = alt.Legend(orient='left')

        ),
        tooltip=["Root Cause"],
    )
    .properties(title="Proportion of root cause", width=300, height=300)
).add_params(selection)


Declare the base table object using the code specified in the link in the docs

Base chart for data tables
ranked_text = alt.Chart(pieChartData).mark_text(align='right', stroke=None, strokeWidth=0).encode(
    y=alt.Y('row_number:O').axis(None)
).transform_filter(
    selection
).transform_window(
    row_number='row_number()'
).transform_filter(
    alt.datum.row_number < 20
).properties(view=alt.ViewConfig(strokeWidth=0))

Note - the alt.ViewConfig(strokeWidth=0) property helped to hide the column borders.
Following this create 'columns' using the base table object like this -
rootCauseField = drawTable(ranked_text, 'Root Cause:N', 'Root Cause')

field1= drawTable(ranked_text, 'Field1:Q', 'Field1')

field2 = drawTable(ranked_text,'Field2:Q', 'Field2')

Combine all the 'columns' next to each other ...
text = alt.hconcat(rootCauseField, field1,field2)

Then concatenate the pie and table next to each other using
pieChart | text

Hope this is of use to others if they need something similar.
